Is deleterow operation through cbt tool in bigtable a background process
Is delete operation in bigtable through deleterow a synchronous operation or does it create a mutation to run in background ?

As per the Documentation delete operation in Bigtable through deleterow is an asynchronous operation. The data is removed up to a week later during compaction, a background process that continuously optimizes the table.
